# Multiple alert criteria not working - alertcondition(condition=((rsiValue > 70) and (close > upper)) or ((rsiValue < 30) and (close < lower))

Tags: pine-script

The alert should trigger once:

```
// Set up alert
alertcondition(condition=((rsiValue > 70) and (close > upper)) or ((rsiValue < 30) and (close < lower)),
     message="alert")
```

It does alert, but only once price returns from being oversold or overbought, not at the instance where price fullfills the above criteria. Any clues?

[image]

A 1 second timeframe is good to speed up testing.

```
//@version=4
study(title="TDIcrossingAlert", overlay=true)

rsiValue = rsi(close, 11)

length = input(50, minval=1)
mult = input(3.0, "Multiplier")
src = input(close, title="Source")
exp = input(true, "Use Exponential MA")
BandsStyle = input("Average True Range", options = ["Average True Range", "True Range", "Range"], title="Bands Style")
atrlength = input(1000, "ATR Length")
esma(source, length)=>
    s = sma(source, length)
    e = ema(source, length)
    exp ? e : s
ma = esma(src, length)
rangema = BandsStyle == "True Range" ? tr(true) : BandsStyle == "Average True Range" ? atr(atrlength) : rma(high - low, length)
upper = ma + rangema * mult
lower = ma - rangema * mult

u = plot(upper, color=#363A45, title="Upper")
l = plot(lower, color=#363A45, title="Lower")

// Set up alert
alertcondition(condition=((rsiValue > 70) and (close > upper)) or ((rsiValue < 30) and (close < lower)),
     message="alert")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your alert isn't firing where you would like because we need to integrate the TDIGM indicator you are using there into the script as one to capture these conditions! Its not a regular RSI in this oscillator, there is some smoothing added. I pushed the two scripts together for you and added another trigger that you might like. There is a plotshape for each to see visually where an equal alert condition would trigger (also included). Keep the plotshape for other scripts for testing! Cheers and take care!

```
    //@version=4
study(title="TDIcrossingAlert", overlay=true)

length          = input(50, minval=1)
mult            = input(3.0, "Multiplier")
src             = input(close, title="Source")
exp             = input(true, "Use Exponential MA")
BandsStyle      = input("Average True Range", options = ["Average True Range", "True Range", "Range"], title="Bands Style")
atrlength       = input(1000, "ATR Length")

rsiPeriod       = input(11, minval = 1, title = "RSI Period")
bandLength      = input(11, minval = 1, title = "Band Length")
lengthrsipl     = input(2,  minval = 0, title = "Fast MA on RSI")
lengthtradesl   = input(6,  minval = 1, title = "Slow MA on RSI")

esma(source, length)=>
   s = sma(source, length)
   e = ema(source, length)
   exp ? e : s
ma      = esma(src, length)
rangema = BandsStyle == "True Range" ? tr(true) : BandsStyle == "Average True Range" ? atr(atrlength) : rma(high - low, length)
upper   = ma + rangema * mult
lower   = ma - rangema * mult

u       = plot(upper, color=#363A45, title="Upper")
l       = plot(lower, color=#363A45, title="Lower")

// TDIGM incorporated into the script to mimic the conditions oof your oscilator 

r       = rsi(src, rsiPeriod)                           // RSI of Close
ma2     = sma(r, bandLength)                            // Moving Average of RSI [current]
offs    = (1.6185 * stdev(r, bandLength))               // Offset
up      = ma2 + offs                                    // Upper Bands
dn      = ma2 - offs                                    // Lower Bands
mid     = (up + dn) / 2                                 // Average of Upper and Lower Bands
fastMA  = sma(r, lengthrsipl)                           // Moving Average of RSI 2 bars back
slowMA  = sma(r, lengthtradesl)                         // Moving Average of RSI 7 bars back

con1 = fastMA > 70 and crossunder(close,upper)
con2 = fastMA > 70 and crossunder(fastMA,slowMA) and (close > upper)[1]

con3 = fastMA < 30 and crossover(close,lower)
con4 = fastMA < 30 and crossover(fastMA,slowMA) and (close < lower)[1]

plotshape(con1, style=shape.xcross,         location=location.abovebar, color=color.yellow, title="Above")
plotshape(con2, style=shape.triangledown,   location=location.abovebar, color=color.red,    title="Overbought")

plotshape(con3, style=shape.xcross,         location=location.belowbar, color=color.yellow, title="Above")
plotshape(con4, style=shape.triangleup,     location=location.belowbar, color=color.green,  title="Overbought")

// Set up alert
alertcondition(con1, "Overbought",          'Overbought on {{interval}} chart. Price is {{close}}')
alertcondition(con2, "Overbought Cross",    'Overbought Cross on {{interval}} chart. Price is {{close}}')

alertcondition(con3, "Oversold",            'Oversold on {{interval}} chart. Price is {{close}}')
alertcondition(con4, "Oversold Cross",      'Oversold Cross on {{interval}} chart. Price is {{close}}')
```